# AWS Glue Workflow to trigger email on any ETL job failure using Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, aws-glue, amazon-ses, aws-glue-workflow

In AWS Glue, I am executing a couple of ETL jobs using workflow, Now I want to inform business via email on the failure of any of the ETL jobs. I need help to get name of failed job and the error caused the job to fail, and pass it to job which would trigger an email using Amazon SES.

It has to be done using only a Glue Workflow to trigger a second job that read the output message from the first job and send the email. Need to perform without using EventBridge for this.

Is it possible to call a glue job/ or python script from within another glue job without passing by glue endpoint and adding a new rule in SG?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/starting-workflow-eventbridge.html) for that. EventBridge supports Glue events.